# Kill Process in windows when the download speed drops

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, batch-file, networking

I am looking for a code in for instance powershell/cmd to kill a process when the download speed goes below 5 mbps.

The situation is that i am using VLC mediaplayer to do live broadcasting. Often it happens that the broadcast goes down or starts having hickups.

The solution is to just restart. But I only restart it when someone complains about not being able to connect.

I am looking for a script/code to monitor this process and automatically restart/kill it when the download speed goes below a certain level or isn't consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Implying VLC reads the content from disk and the speed matches its outbound network speed you can use a disk read speed process performance counter measured for 1 second:

```html
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set LIMIT=500000
set PROCESS=VLC

:LOOP
set line=0
for /f "delims=, tokens=2" %%a in ('typeperf -sc 1 "\Process(%PROCESS%)\IO Read Bytes/sec"') do (
    set /a line+=1
    if !line!==2 (
        set speed=%%a
        set speed=!speed:"=!
        for /f "delims=. tokens=1" %%b in ("!speed!") do set speed=%%b
        if !speed! LSS %LIMIT% (
            taskkill /f /im %PROCESS%.exe
            call RUN-VLC.bat
        )
    )
)
goto LOOP
```

Assuming 5mbps is 500kBps the `LIMIT` is set accordingly to `500000`.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it is a network activity nit a IO activity. So actually nothing is being stored or written to the discs. If this check could be performed with the networkadapters or some sort than it would work. but if i look in the taskmanager VLC has no IO activities only Network.

Comment: If VLC is the only process using the network bandwidth then only the counter name should be changed, which is trivial.

Comment: To what should the counter name changed? And vlc is not the only application using the bandwith so it should be application specific.

Comment: There is no application specific network counter. To view the entire list run `typeperf -q`.

Comment: The workaround for the logic above is to store the stream locally while broadcasting and restart the stream every 24 hours to prevent a full disk.

And while storing the bitrate should be the same as while streaming. So during the stream if a hickup happens than it should stop recording also, which means no IO activity and this could result in a kill...

But this is the only way i suppose if it cannot be covered otherwise....

Comment: Try asking on [VLC support forum](https://forum.videolan.org/), maybe it's a known problem and there are other solutions.

Comment: VLC has no solution to this. This needs to be done with monitoring software  or scripting...But it seems that the only way to do this is by reading IO activity of the harddisk.

Comment: Apparently [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) may be used to measure traffic on the port used by VLC: `tshark -d tcp.port==8888,rtp` (or `http` instead of `rtp` depending on your VLC stream parameters).

Comment: Great! Will have a look at tshark i guess that will be the